# Change file name from within validateBatch?

Tags: fine-uploader

In validateBatch, I check if the file has already been uploaded. If it has, the user has the option to "replace" or "keep both." For the "keep both" option, I need to be able to change the file name before the upload is started. I wanted to use the setName method, but you need the id for that. I tried filtering getUploads by the file name, but from looking at the source code, that doesn't seem to be possible. So I'm not sure how to get the id so I can use the setName method. I also tried updating the file name directly, but of course that didn't work.

My question is what's the proper way to change a file's name from a validate event.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just realized that I can forEach through getUploads() and filter by whichever key I want, but I was hoping there would be a cheaper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in the `onValidate` or `onValidateBatch` event handlers, mostly due to the fact that an ID doesn't exist for the file at this stage. A better option for you wold be to use the [`onSubmit` callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit) instead. Here, you can also reject a file OR you can address the file through the API.